# #include <iostream> in multiple files

Tags: c++, include, iostream

I hope this hasn't been asked before on this site. I wasn't able to find a solid answer from google.

What happens when you #include iostream in multiple files of a project? I always use #ifndef and #define in my header files. Does that prevent iostream from being included more than once?

Comment: Yes, this technique prevents multiple inclusion, and is known as [Include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: The only real danger is it being included more than once in the same Translation Unit, not project, but the standard headers have include guards to my knowledge, yes.

Comment: So, If I am using inheritance, is it a good idea to #include iostream only in the base class? Since the derived classes all depend on the base class, it should guarantee that it only gets included once right?

Comment: @Shan, That's mostly a matter of preference. I see lots of people who prefer including something once in a header that is included by the source for that header, and others, including me, who include every header directly used in every file that directly uses it. Keep in mind that you don't always need to include things in header files if you can either use a forward declaration or don't actually use it *in* the header.

Comment: @chris Cool. Thank you so much for your help. It's for a class assignment and I just wanted make sure so I don't get points taken off for multiple #includes.

Comment: Relevant question, was thinking the same thing myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like chris and Haroogan said, yes they will prevent that.
What the #ifndef and #define are are pre-processor instructions, and are translated in english to

#ifndef (if undefined)

#define (define)

So if you make a header, and #include "myheader.h" twice, then the file will not be included again because you encompassed it in an if statement, which will cause the file to only be included(and defined) when it has not yet been included(defined).

Comment: But there is built-in protection for standard headers?

Comment: @Shan, I can't imagine there would be in a sense of them being special compared to other headers. It sounds like a very unnecessary addition to the standard when compared with a rule that says all standard headers must protect against multiple inclusions.

Answer (score 6):

I had two interpretations of this question:

1. Can you include `iostream` multiple times in the same compilation unit?

   - Yes, safely. All standard headers have include guards so to allow this usage safely.
2. Will using include guards yourself in your code prevent `iostream` from be included multiple times?

   - Surely, as well it would prevent everything in between `#ifndef` and `#endif` (or in a header marked with `#pragma once`, in compilers that support it) from being seen by the compiler more than once... it is just what include guards does, right? But that is not really needed for `#include <iostream>`, because it is already guarded from multiple inclusions.

Answer (score 0):

regardless. you still attempt to include it multiple times even thow you use `ifndef`. because the multiple files will be included once. and all attempt to include `<iostream>` but if you open `<iostream>` it has

```
#pragma once
```

which basically means it will only ever be included once. it is not the advised way to avoid multiple includes i find in the industry. because its harder to know that it wont be included again. compared to seeing ifndef's on the top and bottom.

Comment: It doesn't have to, seeing as how `#pragma once` is non-standard.

Comment: I bet the primary reason is portability.

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt have to? i litually opened the file to check what type of include guards it had. and it has `#pragma once`

Comment: @Zanven, Doesn't have to doesn't mean it can't. All I'm saying is that the standard has no mention of a `#pragma once`, so it can't possibly mandate its use in standard headers. I can't find it, but I would imagine it has something stating that implementations must protect the standard headers from multiple inclusions, and how they do that is up to them, `#pragma once` being a possibility if the implementation supports it.

Comment: yeah i agree that `#pragma once` is a bad way to do it. this is straight from wiki


#pragma once is a non-standard but widely supported preprocessor directive designed to cause the current source file to be included only once in a single compilation. Thus, #pragma once serves the same purpose as #include guards, but with several advantages, including: less code, avoiding name clashes, and sometimes improved compile speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef __IOSTREAM_H
#include <iostream>
#endif

...
```

Seems that most standard headers have a sort of include guard as above.

Alternately you could make your own include guard by defining the required macro.